# How to: Center UICollectionViewCells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I have a collection view data source that is going through a view updates / and has its data reloaded multiple times in the process. Can someone show me how to center the cells after everything is done?

data source method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.testSlice.count
    }
```

current method handling styling the cells and doing a few other things:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true

        print("DEV: testSlice value: \(testSlice)")
        print("DEV: limitedNames value: \(limitedNames)")

        if testSlice != [] {
            cell.profilePicture.playPortalProfilePic(forImageId: testSlice[indexPath.item], { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error requesting profile pic: \(String(describing: error))")

                    if let index = self.testSlice.index(of: "") {
                        self.testSlice.remove(at: index)
                        collectionView.reloadData()


                    }

                }
            }
            )
        } else {
            print("items array was empty, value: \(items)")
        }



        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }
```

I believe I am looking for someone who is great with constraints unless this can be done some other way.

I am trying to center the cells under the label shown

[image: I am trying to center the cells under the label shown]

Comment: What does "center the cells" mean?

Comment: @matt here is a screenshot..sorry should've attached this earlier. https://gyazo.com/c619f6e4a5cbff2e042a568b9be2f703 my goal is to get the remaining cells "centered" with the label shown

Comment: Ok well if that’s all you’ve got, a single row of cells, then the simplest approach is to write your own collection view layout. Trying to make a flow layout do that is kind of a waste in my opinion

Comment: @matt Ok got it will look  into that now.

Comment: Look for carousel layouts, perhaps. They are single horizontal rows of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the cells by adjusting the inset for the section (if you only have one section)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    let widthOfCell = 50 // What ever the width of the cell is 
    let spacingBetweenCells = 10 

    let totalCellWidth = widthOfCell * self.data.count
    let totalSpacingWidth = spacingBetweenCells * (self.data.count - 1)

    let leftInset = (collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2

    if leftInset < 0 {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }

    let rightInset = leftInset

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: rightInset)
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement that solution into the method shown in the question if possible? Cant seem to get that method to work.

Comment: @Joshua its a method in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` you just need to set the collectionView delegate to your viewContorller  `self.collectionView.delegate = self` and add this to your ViewController.

Comment: Keep in mind that this code fails if the needed cell width + spacing is greater than the collection view width. Ensure that the two insets are not negative.